# Non admin users can access a view that is supposed to be restricted to admin users in django rest framework and simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have made a custom user model inside my django backend and I have created a view that register a new user, but I have set the view only for admin users. When I tried to register a new user using a non admin account, it has also worked!! so the view is correct but there is something wrong with the permissions! could someone please tell me what did I do wrong?

this is the models.py that has the custom user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_admin', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, password=password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

this is the view.py that has the registration view:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import permissions, status
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from .models import User

class RegisterView (APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = request.data

            first_name = data['first_name']
            last_name = data['last_name']
            email = data['email']
            password = data['password']
            re_password = data['re_password']
            is_superuser = False

            if password == re_password:
                if len(password)>= 8:
                    if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                        user = User.objects.create_user(
                            first_name = first_name,
                            last_name = last_name,
                            email= email,
                            password=password,
                            is_superuser=is_superuser,
                        )

                        user.save()

                        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                            return Response(
                                {'success': 'Account created successfully!'},
                                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
                            )
                        else:
                            return Response(
                                {'error': 'Something went wrong when trying to register account'},
                                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
                            )
                    else:
                        return Response(
                            {'error': 'Email already exists!'},
                            status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                        )
                else:
                    return Response(
                        {'error': 'Password must be at least 8 Characters in length'},
                        status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                    )
            else:
                return Response(
                    {'error': 'Passwords do not match'},
                    status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )
        except:
            return Response(
                {'error': 'Something went wrong when trying to register account'},
                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )
```

and this is the rest framework settings in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ],
}
```

Comment: Not to ask the obvious question, but have you queried that user just to double check it doesn't actually have the correct flag set - note there are 2 flags - `is_superuser` and `is_staff`. `IsAdminUser` checks the `is_staff` flag, not the `is_superuser` flag.